.NET 8 upgrade error GetAsync System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. Failure to parse near offset 2.Expected an ASCII digit
I have just upgraded our project from .NET 6 (working perfectly fine) to .NET 8. I encounter intermittent issue when sending out request with HttpClient (System.Net.Http) using GetAsync/PostAsync/SendAsync with the following error:

System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. Failure to parse near offset 2. Expected an ASCII digit.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ReadOnlySpan1 args)   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(String format, Object[] args)   at Prometheus.MeterAdapter.TranslateInstrumentDescriptionToPrometheusHelp(Instrument instrument)   at Prometheus.MeterAdapter.OnInstrumentPublished(Instrument instrument, MeterListener listener)   at System.Diagnostics.Metrics.Instrument.Publish()    at System.Diagnostics.Metrics.UpDownCounter1..ctor(Meter meter, String name, String unit, String description, IEnumerable1 tags)     > at  System.Diagnostics.Metrics.Meter.<>c__DisplayClass37_01.b__0()
at System.Diagnostics.Metrics.Meter.GetOrCreateInstrument[T
](Type instrumentType, String name, String unit, String description, IEnumerable1 tags, Func1 instrumentCreator)
at System.Net.Http.Metrics.MetricsHandler..ctor(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, IMeterFactory meterFactory, Meter& meter)
at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.SetupHandlerChain()
at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
at MyService.GetUsers(Guid clientid) in /app/src/Users/contact.cs:line ##

The code:
var url = $"{BaseUrl}/user?contact=12";

// Error happens on this line
var responseData = await _client.GetAsync(url); 

I have another line of code which uses PostAsync, and I get that intermittent error with that call, too:
var url = $"{BaseUrl}/users/search";
var request = new UserSearchRequest
{
     Username = username,
     FamilyId = familyid,
     RelationId = relationid,
};

var requestBody = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

// error happens on this line too
var responseData = await _client.PostAsync(url, requestBody); 

From the log, it doesn't look like the request is sent out at all. What did I do wrong?
Has anybody encounter this issue before? Would anybody help please? Thank you so much.
I have tried using SendAsync as well, and it get that error intermittently just the same. I crossed check all the package updates too for .NET 8, but correct me if I'm wrong, this System.Net.Http library actually comes with .NET 8.
I'm expecting the GetAsync / SendAsync / PostAsync to send out the request with no error as per previous .NET 6 which is already in PRODUCTION.

With nothing further to go on, I would be suspicious of Prometheus.MeterAdapter. I know nothing about this component, but it appears to be right at the point in the call stack where one might suspect your problem to originate. If this is something you can temporarily disable, perhaps try testing without it. If it can be configured, perhaps review the configuration for anything that might not make sense for your use case.

While developing a .Net Core 8 application i faced the same error.
The solution was to update the Nugget Package on all Class Libraries and API to  8.2.1 Version.
<PackageReference Include="prometheus-net" Version="8.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="prometheus-net.AspNetCore" Version="8.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="prometheus-net.AspNetCore.HealthChecks" Version="8.2.1" />


Hello @Emanuel, it was indeed the prometheus-net package. There problem was intermittent, and there was reported bug here
